# How can I make a boat world where everyone lives on boats

Tags: medieval, alternate-worlds, sea

Some people live on land, but a greater part decided to not be confined by dirt.

Living off boats, fishing and traveling around the world... families on boats living all their lives on the sea, seashore, coast... only touching land to short visits.

So how can I make the medieval economy different to allow only a small portion of people remaining static on land?

Comment: When? Where? How? We can't make any answer without any of these details

Comment: @L.Dutch the entire span of the medieval period, worldwide.... boats can move.

Comment: Narrow it down by a lot.. 1000+ years over the entire world fails not only the book test, but even the library test

Comment: This question shows a gross misuderstanding of why the Middle Ages were medieval. Basically, the entire society was structured around a hierarchical system of land tenure. No land, no [feoffment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feoffment), no medieval world. (Oh, and I would strongly suggest to make a rough estimation of how many medieval ships would be needed to carry just half of the population of Constantinople around 1000 CE, and how many men would be needed to build those ships.) (P.S. Neither in the Middle Ages nor in our days is a random fishing boat allowed to fish wherever they please.)

Comment: A little broad of a question in my opinion. You can't just change the world completely and then ask how exactly the economy would change. To point out the significance of such a change try to imagine how a world with out trees would be different. So please make your question more specific and don't ask how build your world from the ground up.

Comment: @AlexP there's no tag for time period spanning rougly the 5th century and the 15th century hence why medieval... also sleeping in a boat vs sleeping in an old mud house... the build cost might be slightly different but the maintainance long run cost might be just the same...since you know common folk houses were made of actual mud

Comment: I'm not sure the economy is the main thing to tweak to make this work, but I gave an answer and tweaked up your question to be cleaner.

Comment: @Fallenspacerock not very broad in my opinion, just remove feuds and everything else that requires lands to keep working.... what remaines... mutate it to allow the existance of a boat world and little remains if you strip out literal continents of people and 1000 years of land-related history and economy

Comment: Also the question, while initially strangely phrased, is well within what we can do. They basically want a justification for most people living on boats with lowish tech, which is a common worldbuilding question. One Piece, say, has most people living on boats.

Comment: @AlexP as a matter of fact the medieval tag actually only says the time period and nothing else... so it was the right tag all along, it specifically says : For questions about the medieval era (500-1500AD o.e.) as a whole, regardless of the location.

Comment: @Xenophile look what you essentially have done with putting most people on boats is completely flipping everything on it's head. I know it can be difficult to sometimes grasp how much one change can completely make your world different. So but what you essentially ask is to create something humongous as an entirely economical system from scratch. Which no one not even someone like me who has studied economics can do for you. An more appropriate question would asking for the biggest economic markets in such a world. This At Least can be answered in less than a book worth of text.

Comment: Economies are based on perception of value. Your story needs to have a value system that supports the boat life style. On earth, boats are highly dependent on land civilizations for food, clothing, ship building materials, sails, and trading. Your world needs to replace all of those and have a value exchange that allows the concentration of resources enough to build and sustain a boat.

Comment: AlexP isn't complaining about the tag, but about the nature of the medieval time period - what made it "medieval." The problem I have (it would have been a Frame Challenge) is that economies, like nature, tend to fall to the lowest energy level. It takes a LOT of energy to keep everyone on high-maintenance, low-accessibility, low-government (therfore high crime) boats. The world would of necessity be very, very mild. The amount of land (an easier place to live) would need to be very, very limited. And yet where did the wood come from? No need for mining or timber? (Oh, boats...). ...

Comment: ... Nothing says you can't have a world like this or a story built in it, but you're asking us to explain it and there won't ever be a satisfactory explanation. Sometimes you need to ignore the ugly details that prove your premise irrational for the sake of a cool story.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Floating islands

The big problem with living in the sea is a lack of accessible resources. There are enormous resources in the oceans but they are floating around diffusely in water and on the ocean floor out of reach of humans. To fix this, have floating islands.

There's some sort of weird plant that forms massive floating colonies in the seas. These have wildlife, wood, and all the resources needed for life on the ocean and rich ecosystems to extract the resources of the sea. Most people can therefore live in ships, going from island to island to collect resources, meet natives.

### Massive volcanic activity

Your planet is extremely tectonically active. This makes land an unpleasant place to live as earthquakes, tsunamis, volcanoes, and other things are common. It makes the sea a great place to live as massive amounts of resources are routinely shot into the water.

While the plants can handle eruptions well, humans cannot, so it's common to live on a boat to avoid the consequences of an eruption. Notably, after an eruption numerous sea monsters swarm around to feast on the innards of volcanoes, and so it's wise to move on.

Comment: how can tsunamis be a problem for land dwellers and not at a problem for boats?

Comment: Easily? Tsunamis are only really an issue near the coast, when you're out on a boast they're mostly underwater and you might not even feel it.

Comment: Yes, plants are well known for handling eruptions well, being really mobile they just wander out of the way of the flowing magma. We see it on documentaries all the time...  I have to admit I'm unfamiliar with the sea monsters that "feast on the innards of volcanoes", though - what, exactly, is a large aquatic lifeform feeding on there?

Comment: The sea blocks magma. This is a fictional world. I wasn't suggesting that sea monsters that feed on magma exist irl.